# Can’t align window properly

Tags: repair, windows, window-frame

I have a window which I believe is a vinyl window. My house was built in 1960 and the previous owner must have changed them.

Upon further inspection, I noticed the window sill looked misaligned so I suspected the window casing was crooked because it sticks out half an inch in one corner.

It turns out the window casing is completely square but the window just doesn’t come into towards the room enough.

It looks great on the exterior, everything appears to be square. How do I bring the window further in? I tried prying the screw to bring it in more but it’ll only budge 1/8”

[image: exterior window]

[image: metal trim, what does this do? The left side is flush to this metal trim but the right has a gap.]

[image: Left side of the window]

[image: Right side of the window]

Comment: Are you trying to resolve a cosmetic issue where the 3/8" difference is visible to you/spouse and bothering you, or is there a mechanical issue with operating the window and you're tying to make it operational again (or make the operation easier so you don't have to force it)?

Comment: If you pull it in 3/8", it will no longer be "correct on the exterior" which is the place where the weather is...

Comment: @FreeMan The window requires shimming because it’s very difficult to open and the wife wants it to look symmetrical. Its actually about a half an inch difference from one side to the other. Looks like someone cut the casing crooked but it’s just the window not coming towards the interior enough.

Comment: @Ecnerwal so there’s no way to correct the window? The window casing is square I just can’t push the window in enough anymore.